# Xubuntu - Move to the workspace instead moving the app to the workspace

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, workspaces

In Ubuntu Mate, when you click on a notification from an app that is working at another workspace, you will be moved to the workspace (at which the app is working). But in Xubuntu it works differently: after clicking on a notification, the app will be moved to the current workspace. Which very quickly ruins the whole purpose of having workspaces for me. Because after 0.5h of work, I end having all apps in one workspace.
Is there any way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: Settings → Window Manager Tweaks → Focus → When a window raises itself: → Switch to window's workspace.

Comment: Confirmed! I wonder why this option is not selected as default...